# Plotting several plots in matplotlib based on conditions from two columns in dataframe Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following dataframe. You can see that each island_id has 1 or more location_id. This dataframe is a very small sample of the real dataframe (13,000,000rows and 4columns).

```
df = {'location_id': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8],
    'timestamp':['2020-05-26 22:00:52','2020-05-26 22:01:52','2020-05-26 22:02:52',
    '2020-05-26 22:00:52','2020-05-26 22:01:52','2020-05-26 22:02:52',
    '2020-05-26 22:00:52','2020-05-26 22:01:52','2020-05-26 22:02:52',
    '2020-05-26 22:00:52','2020-05-26 22:01:52','2020-05-26 22:02:52',
    '2020-05-26 22:00:52','2020-05-26 22:01:52','2020-05-26 22:02:52',
    '2020-05-26 22:00:52','2020-05-26 22:01:52','2020-05-26 22:02:52',
    '2020-05-26 22:00:52','2020-05-26 22:01:52','2020-05-26 22:02:52',
    '2020-05-26 22:00:52','2020-05-26 22:01:52','2020-05-26 22:02:52'],
    'temperature_value': [20,21,22,23,24,25,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44],
    'humidity_value':[60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83],
    'island_id':[10,10,10,20,20,20,20,20,20,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,40,40,40,40,40,40]}
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is to plot the temperature_value of all island_id that have at least 2 location_id. So for example island_id = 30 contains location_id = [4,5,6]. So in this case, I should plot all temperature values for locations 6, 7 and 8 in the same plot and on the x-axis the timestamp. So in my case, I am expecting to get like 20 or 30subplots. Each plot will show the temperature_values of the locations that are in the same island as a function of timestamp.So for an island_id have 3locations, the temperature values for these 3 locations should be shown in the plot(3 curves). (Note: The plots should be under each other, like subplots)

Is there a way to do it in Python ? I would really appreciate it if someone can give me a solution :) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perfect situation where [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) method is designed for. Basically you group by `island_id` and then you iterate the single groups and plot with the condition:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = {'location_id': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7],
'timestamp':['2020-05-26 22:00:52','2020-05-26 22:01:52','2020-05-26 22:02:52',
'2020-05-26 22:00:52','2020-05-26 22:01:52','2020-05-26 22:02:52',
'2020-05-26 22:00:52','2020-05-26 22:01:52','2020-05-26 22:02:52',
'2020-05-26 22:00:52','2020-05-26 22:01:52','2020-05-26 22:02:52',
'2020-05-26 22:00:52','2020-05-26 22:01:52','2020-05-26 22:02:52',
'2020-05-26 22:00:52','2020-05-26 22:01:52','2020-05-26 22:02:52',
'2020-05-26 22:00:52','2020-05-26 22:01:52','2020-05-26 22:02:52'],
'temperature_value': [20,21,22,23,24,25,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41],
'humidity_value':[60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80],
'island_id':[10,10,10,20,20,20,20,20,20,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,40,40,40]}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

print(df)

grouped = df.groupby('island_id')

for isl_id, df_isl in grouped:
    loc_ids = df_isl['location_id'].unique()
    if len(loc_ids) >= 3:
        loc_id_grouped = df_isl.groupby('location_id')
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        for id, df_id in loc_id_grouped:
            x = df_id['timestamp']
            y = df_id['temperature_value']
            ax.plot(x, y)

ax.set_xlabel('location_id')
ax.set_ylabel('temperature_value')

plt.show()
```

This creates three plots, one for each `location_id`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forgot to mention something in my question sorry for that. So the thing is each temperature value is on a given timestamp. So how can I modify or adapt your code in a way to plot the temperature_values on the y-axis and the timestamp on the x-axis. In the end, we'll have line charts for the corresponding locations of each island ?

Comment: So what I exactly wanted is to have for every island that has at least 3 locations to be plotted separately in its own graph. So for example island_id = 40 contains location_id = [6,7,8]. So in this, I should plot all temperature values for locations 6, 7 and 8 in the same plot as a function of there timestamp. There are more than 40 islands that contain more than 3 locations. So how can I plot each of these locations in there separate plot, obtaining in the end like 20 or 30 subplots.

Comment: As you can see there is a step in the `for` loop where you define your `x`. Simply define `x = df['timestamp']` if your timestamp column is called 'timestamp'. For the separate graph do you need different `axis` objects like subplots of the same figure or you need different figures? I will edit my code with [`subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) function.

Comment: I want each of the locations that have the same island to be present in the same plot. Finally obtaining like to 20 to 30 plots. Does it sound a bit clear ? So for example on the first plot locations 6,7,8 ; Second plot locations 20,30,40,50; 3rd plot etc.. Ofcourse with there corresponding labels I don't know how this can be done if it should be done manually or better to do it as a function. Finally having in total 30 subplots , each plot representing all locations of a specific island.

Comment: Thank you very much. However in this case, if I want to use the timestamp instead on the x-axis instead of having the ids, what should I do ? Where should I define it, and how can I show it in the plot ?

Comment: It depends on how your DataFrame looks like. you have to define it where I'm defining it in my code in the second for loop. That second for loop could be iterating another `groupby('location_id')` for example. If you provide a subset of the DataFrame that also contains the timestamps I can have a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217305/discussion-between-aboudi-shukor-and-francesco).

Answer (score 1):

`.groupby`, and `filter`  'location_id' whose count equals or more than three into a new datframe.

```
df2=df.groupby('island_id').filter(lambda x:x.location_id.nunique()>=2)
```

Plot

```
g=df2.groupby(['location_id','island_id'])
for x, df in g:
    df.plot(kind='bar', x='timestamp',y=['temperature_value', 'humidity_value'])
    plt.title(x)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I forgot to mention something in my question that each temperature value is on a given timestamp. So how can I modify or adapt your code in a way to plot the temperature_values on the y-axis and the timestamp on the x-axis. In the end, we'll have line charts for the corresponding locations of each island.

Comment: What I needed specifically since my real data is huge is expecting to obtain like 30 plots because there a lot of islands that have more than 3 locations. So how I can plot each of island with it's corresponding locations separately. For example island_id = 40 , has locations [6,7,8] and assume that island_id = 100 has locations [20,30,40]. I need to plot them both under each other. As I mentioned before I'm expecting to have 20plots or 30plots. How is it also possible to label each of the locations. I don't know if that can be done.

Comment: Can you please edit the question and provide the timestamp as well?

Comment: I edited the question and added the timestamp. Thank for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217315/discussion-between-aboudi-shukor-and-wwnde).